# Configuring a single build output folder in a .Net 6 solution

Tags: .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I have a solution that contains a WPF project and numerous class libraries. Some of these class lib projects form part of a bespoke "plugin" framework and are *not* referenced by the WPF (startup) project. During a build I need all of these class lib assemblies in the same build output folder as the WPF project exe, so it can discover them at runtime (although this is irrelevant to this question). In VS2019, this was easily done by setting each project's "build output folder" setting to point to the same folder.

Having recently migrated the solution/projects to .Net 6, I've noticed that the above project setting is now called "base output path", and during a build VS appends additional subfolders to this based on the project's configuration and TFM. For example if I set the projects' "base output path" to `\foobar\BuildOutput` then the WPF project ends up in `\foobar\BuildOutput\x64\debug\net6.0-windows\` while the class lib projects end up in `\foobar\BuildOutput\x64\debug\net6.0\`.

Other than using a post build script, is there any way to ensure that all project assemblies end up in one build output folder, regardless of TFM?

**Edit** - I guess the obvious answer is simply to change the target framework in those class library project files to `net6.0-windows`. Is there any downside in doing this, like pulling in all sorts of frameworks/packages that the project doesn't need? Those class libs will never be used by anything other than this (Windows) desktop application.

Comment: The obvious answer is to *not* depend on the debug output folder in the first place. You won't deploy the debug binaries after all. When you *publish* your project, the target folder will contain all necessary libraries. `net6.0` isn't for class libraries, it's for *cross-platform* files. Unless you specifically target Windows, a Console app will be cross platform

Comment: The real build output folder is the publish folder, and that can be redirected anywhere you want from the command line or VS switches. You may want to create a single-file executable for example, which will contain all necessary DLLs in a single `.exe` file. Or you may create a standalone *and* single file executable, which will contain both the runtime and application files.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#appendtargetframeworktooutputpath) project setting to eliminate the per framework output folder.

`<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>`